# ext.net combobox unable to load data from database

Tags: model-view-controller, data-binding, combobox, ext.net

I also tried the following code..trying with a handler

in Index.aspx

```
<ext:Store ID="Store1" IsPagingStore="true" runat="server">

             <Proxy>
                        <ext:AjaxProxy Url="../../Shared/JsonHandler.ashx">
                            <ActionMethods Read="GET" />
                            <Reader>

                                <ext:JsonReader Root="names" />
                            </Reader>
                        </ext:AjaxProxy>
                    </Proxy>
           <Model>
            <ext:Model ID="Model1" runat="server">
            <Fields>
            <ext:ModelField Name="name" Type="String" Mapping="nameList"  />

            </Fields>
            </ext:Model>
             </Model>
            </ext:Store>
            </Store>
```

In JsonHandler.ashx

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType ="text/json";
        var requestParams = new StoreRequestParameters(context);

        FormExampleController ex=new FormExampleController ();

        var list = ex.getValue();

        context.Response.Write(string.Format("{{'Names':{0}}}",JSON.Serialize(list)));


    }
```

In FormController

```
public List<string> getValue()
    {
        FormUser user = new FormUser();
        user.nameList = new List<string>
        {
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D"

        };
        return user.nameList;
    }
```

Here again the values are getting passed to the handler, but the combobox is shown as empty!!Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a sample of what `nameList` is. Is it a `List<string>`, or maybe a `comma,separated,list,of,strings`? If an `Array` of `strings`, you will require an `ArrayReader`.

Comment: Yes it is a list of strings.. and I am passing it from the controller.Here is the code    public ActionResult Index()
        {
            FormUser user = new FormUser();
            user.nameList = new List<string>
            {
                "A",
                "B",
                "C",
                "D"
                
            };
          //  ViewBag.namelist = user.nameList;
            return View(user);
        }

Comment: As per your suggestion I tried adding arrayreader to my store..however I am not able to add Fields and ext:Recordfield, it says fields not supported..Inside the readertag I am able to add only a customconfig

Comment: Interestingly, it appears binding a simple List or Array of strings to a Store is not possible. The store is expecting something a little more complex in structure. I am investigating a solution. I will also post an answer with a test case below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears binding the `Store` to a simple `List` or `Array` of strings is not possible.

The following is a test case that should work, but doesn't. I'm investigating a solution and will post an update soon.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %> 

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var store = this.ComboBox1.GetStore();

        store.DataSource = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        store.DataBind();
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

    <ext:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" DisplayField="name">
        <Store>
            <ext:Store runat="server">
                <Model>
                    <ext:Model runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <ext:ModelField Name="name" />
                        </Fields>
                    </ext:Model>
                </Model>
            </ext:Store>
        </Store>
    </ext:ComboBox>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The following sample binds to a simple `List<object>`, although obviously this is not a solution to the original problem, but I present here as a possible temporary work-around.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %> 

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var store = this.ComboBox1.GetStore();

        store.DataSource = new List<object> { 
            new { name = "A" }, 
            new { name = "B" }, 
            new { name = "C" }, 
            new { name = "D" } 
        };

        store.DataBind();
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

    <ext:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" DisplayField="name">
        <Store>
            <ext:Store runat="server">
                <Model>
                    <ext:Model runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <ext:ModelField Name="name" />
                        </Fields>
                    </ext:Model>
                </Model>
            </ext:Store>
        </Store>
    </ext:ComboBox>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply..but actually the ultimate aim is to load a list from databse to the combo...hence explicitly giving values like new {name="A"} may not work...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such plain structure is not supported by Store. Store expects collection of objects (object should contain properties which are defined as fields in model)

You should transform your List of string to List of object, like

```
(new List<string>{"a", "b", "s"}).Select(s => new {FieldName = s})
```